# Search Templates | Loading & Caching the script file locally

Tags: elasticsearch

**Context:**

- We are moving from ES 5.X to ES 7.X
- Earlier we were using JEST Client, now we are planning to use ES High-Level Client
- Our search queries are complex and we are planning to use SearchTemplate API
- We will store template files locally & cache them to reduce the overhead of I/O

**What I have tried so far:**

- I've read the documentation of EHLC and I can't find a mechanism to load & cache script files directly from the file system
- I can see that we can store the script in E.S which we don't want to do, assumingly we won't be having changelogs there.

**Question:**

- Is there an inbuilt mechanism to use the locally stored file as a script in EHLC? OR we shall use inline scripts and load & cache the script file using custom code

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use search templates stored directly in ES?

Comment: Our ES query is very big and there are frequent changes in that as well... I prefer to track the changes using git...I think of locally storing the query (for change tracking) and on application- startup publishing the same to stored script and using the script-key to access the same ... but it may pose some issue during release - machines with old code start accessing the new query ... I am thinking of a way to solve that as well

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments I'd suggest the following:

1. Keep track of the templates with git.
2. Monitor the changes and trigger a pub/sub message whenever applicable (PR merges etc.).
3. Configure your pub/sub handler to update the stored search template in ES.

Otherwise, when we talk about local loading + caching, the machines with slightly older EHLC processes wouldn't get notified about the most recent changes in git and would continue using stale scripts.